# C++ while loops on my program

Tags: c++, optimization, while-loop, helper, do-while

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    double Donor = 0.0;
    int totalRaised = 0;

    cout << "Enter amount donated by first donor [or -1 to stop]:" << endl;
    cin >> Donor;

    while (Donor != -1)
    {
        cout << "Enter amount donated by next donor [or -1 to stop]:" << endl;
        cin >> Donor;
        totalRaised = totalRaised + Donor;
    }
    cout << "Total amount of money raised: " << totalRaised << endl;

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

This is my code and my goal is to have the user put the input in and when done enter in -1 and display the total amount enter from the user but my problem when I run this code I do not get the correct value. Could someone point me in the right direction and explain how to make the program run correctly. Thank you.

Comment: You're reading in the first value with the first "cin >> Donor;" but not storing it in totalRaised, so in the while loop you just overwrite it.  Your first value is always going to be lost.  If you just add the line "totalRaised = totalRaised + Donor" after the first "cin >> Donor" it will work (although as an aside the practice of evaluating equality to -1 for floating point numbers is frowned upon for good reason)

Comment: Give some sample inputs and outputs, please.

Comment: Please get rid of the `system("pause");`. It is simply [dangerous, inefficient, and marks you as a poor programmer](http://www.gidnetwork.com/b-61.html) to anyone who looks at your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
while (Donor != -1)
    {
        cout << "Enter amount donated by next donor [or -1 to stop]:" << endl;
        totalRaised = totalRaised + Donor;
        cin >> Donor;
    }
```

see if it works.

you have to add the first `input` which was before the `while loop` and then go for the next input